# Удаление записей в таблице

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня есть таблица table1, у которое есть столбец field1(bigint[])
У меня есть вторая таблица table, у которой есть поле id
Я бы хотел сделать такой запрос, который берет поочередно все строки из первой таблицы. К примеру, взяли строку со значением:

```
[1001, 1005]
```

Во второй таблице у меня могут быть записи такие

```
1001
2001
2321
1005
```

Я бы хотел оставить запись с минимальным значением из взятого массива первой таблицы. Т.е из [1001, 1005], я оставляю 1001, а все записи с 1005 - удаляю. И должно получиться:

```
1001
2001
2321
```

Я думал, что это делается примерно так, как мне посоветовали делать с оператором UPDATE. Но это не работает.

```
DELETE FROM table2
FROM (
      SELECT (SELECT min(x) FROM unnest(field1)as x) min_val,
             unnest(field1) val
        FROM table1
  ) q
WHERE id <> min_val and id = val;
```

Comment: `delete from table2 where id in ( select ... )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Экстенсивно:

```sql
DELETE 
FROM table2 
USING ( SELECT separate_values.value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY table1.fiedl1) rn
        FROM table1
        CROSS JOIN UNNEST(table1.fiedl1) AS separate_values (value) ) AS criteria
WHERE id = criteria.value
  AND criteria.rn > 1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c9d597d071609dc6b822cc2f46f565e3

Если надо оставить не первый, а минимальный - добавьте соотв. ORDER BY в определение окна.